# Where does .NET's Debug.Write() output to?

Tags: .net

I didn't see any output in the console or Visual Studio's output panel from:

```
Debug.Write("WriteStatements() was reached")
```

Where does the output go to?

Comment: If you don't see the output in Visual Studio's *Output* window make sure that you have selected *Show output from Debug* in the drop-down list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It writes to the default trace listener, which you would need to turn on:

> [Debug.Write Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54ffa64k.aspx)

If you want this directed to the console you would need to add an instance of the [ConsoleTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener.aspx):

In your .config file ensure you have the following entries:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="configConsoleListener" 
          type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You may also need to ensure that you've included the `/d:TRACE` flag when compiling your project to enable the output.

Comment: @Ricky There is a DefaultTraceListener (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.aspx), which will apparently "emit the message to the Win32 OutputDebugString function and to the Debugger.Log method. For information about the OutputDebugString  function, see the Platform SDK or MSDN", but you wanted it in the Console/Output window, which needs the ConsoleTraceListener.

Comment: Didn't see your comment until I had posted my answer, sorry.

Comment: @divo - No worries, you make a good point about DebugView picking it up, and also the note about release builds ;)

Answer (score 16):

Zhaph's answer already told you a way to get to the output of `Debug.Write`.

Under the hood, the default listener for `Debug.Write`, i.e. `System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener`, calls the Windows API function [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Any message passed to that function can be displayed by a debugger, e.g. you will see the output in the *Output* window of Visual Studio.

Another quite simple way to see the output of `Debug.Write` and/or `Trace.Write` is to use [**DebugView**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx), a tool from Sysinternals:

> DebugView is an application that lets
>   you monitor debug output on your local
>   system, or any computer on the network
>   that you can reach via TCP/IP. It is
>   capable of displaying both kernel-mode
>   and Win32 debug output, so you don't
>   need a debugger to catch the debug
>   output your applications or device
>   drivers generate, nor do you need to
>   modify your applications or drivers to
>   use non-standard debug output APIs.

Please note, that `Debug.Write` statements will not be included in a Release build, hence you would only see the output in the Debug build.

Comment: I have to say, this was a phenomenal tool when debugging tests. Sometimes you need to see the output without the debugger running. Thanks Dirk!