# How to use Console.WriteLine in ASP.NET (C#) during debug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, console

I want to write some result to the console in ASP.NET (C#).
It works in a Window application, but a Web application does not work.
Here is what I have tried:

```
protected void btonClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You click me ...................");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("You click me ..................");
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("You click me ..................");
}
```

But I see nothing in the Output panel. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: look Here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522099/where-does-debug-write-output-to

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Console.Write will not work in ASP.NET as it is called using the browser. Use Response.Write instead.

See Stack Overflow question *[Where does Console.WriteLine go in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137660)*.

If you want to write something to Output window during debugging, you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SomeText");
```

but this will work only during debug.

See Stack Overflow question *[Debug.WriteLine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370449)*.

Comment: Response.Write will write to the http response stream ,I dont think @Leap Bun wants that

Comment: @labroo Of course. Respone.Write will display text to browser. I can't use it.

Comment: @PraveenVenu I already tried System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SomeText"); in the question!

Comment: Note that you can change the output of System.Diagnostics.Debug by manipulating the Listeners collection. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener.aspx) for more info

Comment: Is your Output window is in Debug mode? and <compilation debug="true"> in web.config?

Comment: All I see is a bunch of Application Insights Telemetry crap.  My debug messages don't show up.

Answer (score 34):

`using System.Diagnostics;`

The following will print to your output as long as the dropdown is set to 'Debug' as shown below.

`Debug.WriteLine("Hello, world!");`

---

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If for whatever reason you'd like to catch the output of `Console.WriteLine`, you CAN do this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var writer = new LogWriter();
    Console.SetOut(writer);
}

public class LogWriter : TextWriter
{
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        //do whatever with value
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.Default; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Trace.Write("Error Message") and Trace.Warn("Error Message") are the methods to use in web, need to decorate the page header trace=true and in config file to hide the error message text to go to end-user and so as to stay in iis itself for programmer debug.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't launch as an IIS server. check your launch setting, make sure it switched to your project name( change this name in your `launchSettings.json` file ), not the IIS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use response.write method in the [code-behind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind).

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you start your application in Debug mode (<kbd>F5</kbd>), not without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) and then select "Show output from: Debug" in the Output panel in Visual Studio.