# How do i Redirect Console.Write to TextBox of asp.net web page.Is there any way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

What is a good way to redirect console output to asp.net Text-box on Web page?
If I have an existing program that has console.Write , do I need to overload the function in Web page Text-box.I have TextBox on web page and I Want to display console.Write output in TextBox. Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Console.WriteLine in ASP.NET (C#) during debug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614218/how-to-use-console-writeline-in-asp-net-c-during-debug)

Comment: To summarize the duplicate: it can't be used in ASP.NET, slightly similar functionality can only be achieved using `Debug.Write` or (if you don't mind that your HTML output gets mangled) `Response.Write`.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Write` is used to put output on a console. I will not work in Asp.Net. Asp.Net text box control text can be set like `textBoxName.Text = "some value"`.

If you would like to write some text to Asp.Net response stream, you may use [Response.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomWriter : TextWriter
{
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        textBox1.Text += value + Environment.NewLine
    }

    // ... etc.
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Console.SetOut(new CustomWriter());
```