# How do I write to console in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I've already tried using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614249/2852699), but nothing is written to console when I put a `WriteLine` call at the top of my `Startup.ConfigureServices` method then run the ASP.NET application locally with `dotnet run -c debug`.

For other reasons I can't just use the [`ILogger` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (trying to debug logging some Application Insights initializers so can't get an `ILogger` instance).

Using .NET Core 3.1.201. Steps to reproduce:

1. Open console, move to empty directory and type `dotnet new web`
2. Open generated project, add `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TEST TEST TEST");` to the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method
3. Open the `appsettings.development.json` file and set all log levels to `Debug`
4. Run `dotnet run -c debug` and view console output; there will be no `TEST TEST TEST` string present:

```
PS C:\Users\ahelwer\source\prototype\test> dotnet run -c debug
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1]
      Hosting starting
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[2]
      Failed to locate the development https certificate at '(null)'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[0]
      Using development certificate: CN=localhost (Thumbprint: 9C942CB86D28BD34EC038AC614E1D069646F30E7)
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[0]
      Loaded hosting startup assembly test
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\ahelwer\source\prototype\test
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started
```

Contents of `appsettings.development.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TEST TEST TEST TEST");`
etc.

Comment: WriteLine is the way. Your Configureservices method is not being called.

Comment: It most certainly is. It contains a number of other authentication & authorization configuration methods which are definitely being added.

Comment: I added steps to reproduce.

Comment: Minimum log level are you using? In case that is information then debug not will be shown

Comment: Set all log levels to debug (see edited post); same thing.

Comment: Did you try Console.WriteLine? What did you get get? Is switching to a more flexible logging system, such as [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) an option?

Comment: @lex-li what do you mean by "the new logger"? `ILogger`?

Comment: @LexLi that's completely wrong. Not only does the doc you linked to say you can (optionally) attach a trace listener and not that one is required, but also its for .Net Framework; OP's question is relating to .Net Core. There is no guidance from MS to stop using the Debug class and use the 'new logger'.